# Insert an invisible input field in a Django / Bootstrap crispy form, before the password field

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django / Bootstrap crispy form for registering a new user:

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Fieldset, ButtonHolder, Submit

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'autocomplete':'off',}))
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                '',
                'username',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'password'
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
            )
        )
```

The problem is that the browser autocomplete fills in the email and password fields. The HTML generated by Django crispy forms around the password is as follows:

```
<div id="div_id_password" class="control-group">
    <label for="id_password" class="control-label requiredField">
        Password
        <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input name="password" autocomplete="off" required="" id="id_password"
            class="textinput textInput" type="password">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I understand that turning autocomplete off does not work. So I would like to do the usual trick of inserting an invisible field (`display:none`) just before the password via Django crispy forms, so that the result is:

```
<div id="div_id_password" class="control-group">
    <label for="id_password" class="control-label requiredField">
        Password
        <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;">
        <input name="password" autocomplete="off" required="" id="id_password"
            class="textinput textInput" type="password">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a nice way to insert this HTML via Djano crispy forms, unless there is another way to prevent the autocomplete?

I am using Firefox / Linux Mint.

Comment: try to set the `autocomplete="off"` in the form tag not the input : )

Comment: @mohammedqudah I set the form attributes using: self.helper.attrs = {'autocomplete':'off',}  So autocomplete is off for the form, but it still didn't have any effect.

Comment: are you sure it is adding this attr? inspect the code.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the inspector shows: <form autocomplete="off" method="post">

Comment: are you using firefox?

Comment: Yes, version 57 (64 bit).

Comment: oh, firefox ignore `autocomplet="off"` for passwords so your problem now is *force set autocomplete in firefox input*, that what i know : )

Answer (score 0):

I used JavaScript / jQuery to fix this problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearPassword()
    {
        $('#id_password').val('');
    }
    window.onload = clearPassword;
</script>
```